# On the variation of a Kähler metric on a surface by pullback of the complex structure

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, complex-geometry

Let $\Sigma$ be a compact, connected, oriented surface, and let $\rho\in\Omega^2(\Sigma)$ be a fixed volume form. Then any (almost) complex structure $J\in\Omega^0(M;\operatorname{End}TM)$ compatible with the orientation gives us a Riemannian metric via
$$g(-,-) = \rho(-,J-).$$
Now let $\psi:\Sigma\to\Sigma$ be a diffeomorphism. Then $\tilde{J} = \psi^*J$ induces a possibly different metric $\tilde{g}$. We have
$$\begin{align}
\tilde{g}(-,-) = & \rho(-,\tilde{J}-)\\
= & \rho(-,d\psi^{-1}(J\circ\psi)d\psi-)\\
= & ((\psi^{-1})^*\rho)(d\psi-,(J\circ\psi)d\psi-)
\end{align}$$
and as $(\psi^{-1})^*\rho$ at $\psi(m)$ is given by $f(\psi(m))\rho_{\psi(m)}$, where $f:\Sigma\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is some function, we obtain
$$\tilde{g} = \psi^*(fg).$$
I need to find $f$ in function of $\psi$ (as this would allow me, for example, to understand how the curvature changes when we change $J$ by the pullback via a diffeomorphism). Are there known results for this? Any help or hint on how to proceed would be appreciated.

---

**Notes:** The following things are true in the case I need, but I don't know whether they are useful:

- The genus of $\Sigma$ is at least $2$.
- The diffeomorphism $\psi$ can be taken to be homotopic to the identity.
- As $\rho$ can be thought of as a symplectic form, we are in fact working with Kähler metrics.

**My progress:**

Write $\phi=\psi^{-1}$, $x=\psi(m)$. Let $v_1,v_2\in T_x\Sigma$, $w_1,w_2\in T_{\phi(x)}\Sigma$ be bases and write
$$d\phi_x\cdot(a^iv_i) = d\phi_i^jw_j.$$
Then (using Einstein summation convention):
$$\begin{align}
(\phi^*\rho)_x(a^iv_i,b^jv_j) = & \rho_{\phi(x)}(d\phi_i^ka^iw_k,d\phi_j^lb^jw_l)\\
= & d\phi_i^ka^id\phi_j^lb^j\rho_{\phi(x)}(w_k,w_l)
\end{align}$$
and using the fact that $\rho_{\phi(x)}(w_k,w_l)$ is zero if $k=l$ and writing down explicitly all the summands:
$$\begin{align}
= & \rho_{\phi(x)}(w_1,w_2)\big(d\phi_i^1a^id\phi_j^2b^j - d\phi_i^2a^id\phi_j^1b^j\big)\\
= & \rho_{\phi(x)}(w_1,w_2)\big(d\phi_i^1a^id\phi_j^2b^j - d\phi_i^2a^id\phi_j^1b^j\big)\\
= & \det\pmatrix{b^1&a^1\\b^2&a^2}\det(d\phi_x)\rho_{\phi(x)}(w_1,w_2).
\end{align}$$
At the same time, we have:
$$\rho_x(a^iv_i,b^jv_j) = \det\pmatrix{b^1&a^1\\b^2&a^2}\rho_x(w_1,w_2),$$
so that we conclude:
$$(\phi^*\rho)_x = \frac{\rho_{\phi(x)}(w_1,w_2)}{\rho_x(v_1,v_2)}\det(d\phi_x)\rho_x.$$
The first term compensates for the changes in the determinant coming from a change of basis, so that this expression is independent of choice.

Is there a nicer way to write down this formula (without having to write terms a priori dependent from the choice of basis)?

Answer (score 1):

Let us use local coordinates $x^1$, $x^2$ around $x_0$, and local coordinates $y^1$, $y^2$ around $y_0 = \phi(x_0)$. Assume that around $x_0$, we have

$\rho = h(x) dx^1 \wedge dx^2$

and that around $y$, we have

$\rho = k(y) dy^1 \wedge dy^2$.

We then have

$\phi^*(\rho) = k(\phi(x)) \det(\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j}) dx^1 \wedge dx^2$

Comparing, we get that $f(x) = \frac{k(\phi(x))}{h(x)} \det(\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j})$

This is equivalent to the OP's formula (with a shorter proof perhaps). There is probably some way of writing this more invariantly, but I don't think it can be simplified much further, to answer the OP's question.

Comment: I deleted my old comment. Notice that your present answer is exactly what I wrote down in "my progress", simply by taking $v_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ and $w_j = \frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}$. Although it is certainly a cleaner way of obtaining it.

Comment: yes I know. I can edit it a bit to say that we got equivalent formulae. I don't expect it to be simplifiable much further, to answer your question.